# Configure "Do not disturb" to disable all sounds but phone calls in Oreo

Tags: 8.0-oreo, do-not-disturb

I'm using Android 8.0. For a few months I've been using "Do not disturb" with "Alarms only" and it worked as expected (the phone was completely silent, even when I picked it up to go into Twitter/Whatsapp, etc.).

I was, however, missing calls, so I recently switched to "Priority only". Unfortunately, the phone is now emitting sounds that I do not appreciate (when clicking Whatsapp's voice note or when updating my Twitter feed, for example). I have managed to disable some of them in-app, but others I can't find. They are automatically muted when using "Alarms only", though.

Is there any way to have Android be *completely* silent except for alarms and calls? Playing around Settings did not help. The phone is a **Xiaomi Mi A1**.

Comment: What phone is this for?  In the DND settings, depending on phone, there should be options for behavior for Calls where you can set them to "From anyone", "Contacts only", "Starred Contacts Only", or "None".  Should be in Settings - Sound - Do Not Disturb (Pixel 2 XL).

Comment: @DukeSilversJazz I've updated the question with the phone model. The setting I see to configure calls is for "Priority Only" only. I have the calls properly configured, the problem is that other sounds are also enabled and I can't see where to disable them.